# How many unique rotating sequences?

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

This is a small puzzle I've been playing with for the past couple of days:

**For some length N, how many unique sequences of digits can be created when any 'rotation' of the digits is considered as the same sequence?**

Examples of equivalent sequences under this definition (that is, each column of values is considered one sequence):

N=3

123  445 777
312  544
231

N=4

1234
4123
3412
2341

Note: In the above example for N=4, 1324 is considered distinct from 1234, because 1324 cannot be reached by rotating 1234.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Unique rotating sequences" of the kind you describe are called [necklaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29).  According to the linked article on Wikipedia, the number of $k$-ary necklaces of length $N$ is given by
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{d\;\vert\;N}\varphi(d)k^{N/d},
$$
where $k=10$ if you're considering strings of the digits $0...9$, the sum is over the divisors of $N$, and $\varphi(d)$ is [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), or the number of positive integers less than $d$ that are relatively prime to $d$.

Comment: Wow, that looks like to answer the puzzle - thanks! You wouldn't happen to have any intuition to a closed-form solution would you? This final inquiry is purely out of curiosity (I'm marking this correct).

Comment: On second thought, such an equation would require some closed-form equation for finding primes. Nevermind!